# API Flower как отправить запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Пытаюсь через API Flower передать воркеру путь к папке /path/папка,
Работает, только если в аргументах список с цифрами  data = '{"args":[1,2]}' # если INT работает.
Как сделать, чтобы в аргументах отправлялся путь к папке. /path/папка

log flower:
Expecting value: line 1 column 10 (char 9)

таск:

````
import requests, json


def get_path_json():
    return os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())


def on_raw_message(body):
    print(body)


def exists(path):
    return os.stat(path)


def uptasks(task):
   
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

    #data = get_path_json() # не работает return 400
    data = '{"args":[1,2]}' # если INT передать работает return 200
    print(data)
    response = requests.post(f'http://address-flower/api/task/send-task/{task}',
                             headers=headers, data=data.encode('utf-8'), auth=('', ''))

    return response.status_code```

воркер:


```from celery import Celery
import re
import os
import subprocess
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote
import json
from datetime import datetime

from celery.beat import logger

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
BACKEND_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
app = Celery('tasks', broker=BROKER_URL, backend=BACKEND_URL)





def getdate():
    """Date time Now"""
    return "%s" % datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H")


@app.task()
def slice_name(path):
    print(path)
    with open(f'{path}/metadata.json') as f:
        time = getdate()
        templates = json.load(f)
        files = templates.get('meeting_url')
        str_files = ''.join(files)
        re_files = re.split(r'/', str_files)[-1]
        str_files_list = '_'.join(re_files)
        result_files = re_files + f'_{time}_Record.mp4'
        return {'record': unquote(result_files),
                'name': re_files}```
````

Comment: Ну, написать синтаксически корректный JSON наверное? `data = '{"args":["/path/папка"]}'`

Comment: Работает. Спасибо